# How encode in base64 a file generated with jspdf and html2canvas?

Tags: javascript, jspdf, html2canvas

i'm trying encode the document generated in the attached code, but nothing happens, not generate  error but neither encodes the file, and the `ajax` `request` is never executed

what is the correct way?

```
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("workAreaModel"), {
    onrendered: function(canvas)
    {
        var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        var doc = new jsPDF("l", "pt", "letter");
        doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG',20,20);
        var fileEncode = btoa(doc.output());
         $.ajax({
              url: '/model/send',
              data: fileEncode,
              dataType: 'text',
              processData: false,
              contentType: false,
              type: 'GET',
              success: function (response) {
                   alter('Exit to send request');
              },
              error: function (jqXHR) {
                  alter('Failure to send request');
              }
             });
    }
});
```

Comment: What does `doc.output()` return? Is `"/model/send"` expecting `GET` request?

Comment: Without debug steps and output, this is at risk of being closed as an instance of a "Why is this code not working" question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First, jsPDF is not native in javascript, make sure you have included proper source, and after having a peek on other references, I think you don't need btoa() function to convert doc.output(), just specify like this :

```
 doc.output('datauri');
```

Second, base-64 encoded string is possible to contain **' + '** , **' / '** , **' = '**, they are not **URL safe** characters , you need to replace them or you cannot deal with ajax .

However, in my own experience, depending on file's size, it's easy to be hell long ! before reaching the characters' length limit of GET method, encoded string will crash your web developer tool first, and debugging would be difficult.

My suggestion, according to your jquery code

```
processData: false,
contentType: false
```

It is common setting to send maybe **File** or **Blob** object,
just have a look on jsPDF, it is availible to convert your data to blob :

```
doc.output('blob');
```

so revise your code completely :

```
var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
var doc = new jsPDF("l", "pt", "letter");
doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG',20,20);
var file = doc.output('blob');
var fd = new FormData();     // To carry on your data  
fd.append('mypdf',file);

$.ajax({
   url: '/model/send',   //here is also a problem, depends on your 
   data: fd,           //backend language, it may looks like '/model/send.php'
   dataType: 'text',
   processData: false,
   contentType: false,
   type: 'POST',
   success: function (response) {
     alter('Exit to send request');
   },
   error: function (jqXHR) {
     alter('Failure to send request');
   }
});
```

and if you are using php on your backend , you could have a look on your data information:

```
echo $_FILES['mypdf'];
```

Comment: Thank you, i need use  doc.output('blob');

Comment: Carr, why are you missing the url encode step? That the url is save?

Comment: @Arendax ,`doc.output('datauri')` already gives you a binary data string that encoded in base64.

Comment: @Carr okay but I needed to use `doc.output('blob');`. After all I didn't use your way and used an other one so never mind.

Comment: Update for 2021, this needs to be doc.output("datauristring")

Answer (score 2):

This code is for capturing Html page from screen and save as Pdf and send to back end api As blob

```
const filename = 'form.pdf';
    const thisData = this;
    this.printElement = document.getElementById('content');
     html2canvas(this.printElement).then(canvas => {
      this.pdfData = new jsPDF ('p', 'mm', 'a4');
      this.imageHeight = canvas.height * 208 / canvas.width;
      this.pdfData.addImage(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'), 'PNG', 0, 0, 208, this.imageHeight);
      this.pdfData.save(filename);
      this.uploadFile(this.pdfData.output('blob'));
    });
  }
  uploadFile(pdfFile: Blob) {
    this.uploadService.uploadFile(pdfFile)
      .subscribe(
       (data: any) => {
        if (data.responseCode === 200 ) {
          //succesfully uploaded to back end server
        }},
       (error) => {
         //error occured
       }
     )
  }
```