# Render PDF Using jsPDF and HTML2Canvas, and Attach in Email Using NodeMailer

Tags: javascript, jspdf, nodemailer, html2canvas

I have an application where people can review advertising contracts and accept / deny them.  On acceptance of the contract I want to render a PDF of it and then attach that PDF in an email that gets sent out to the customer for their records.  The problem is that I'm not exactly sure how to do this utilizing `jsPDF` and `HTML2Canvas` with `NodeMailer` as the email package.  Looking at the documentation of `jsPDF` it looks like you can only download the PDF locally, but I want to be able to store this in an array and send as an attachment through `NodeMailer`.  I'm able to send an email with a PDF attachment, but the problem is that the PDF is blank, which tells me the way I'm doing it is not correct.

This is where I'm creating and attempting to store the PDF:

```
AcceptContract(){
        let curr = this.state.CurrentContract;
        let stores = this.state.StoresSelected;

        if(this.state.CurrentContract <= this.state.TotalContracts){
            if(this.state.CurrentContract != this.state.TotalContracts){
                curr++
            }

            stores[this.state.CurrentContract - 1].ContractStatus = "ACCEPTED"
            this.GeneratePDF();
            this.setState({
                CurrentContract: curr,
                StoresSelected: stores,
            })

        }else if(this.state.CurrentContract == this.state.TotalContracts){
            console.log('render final button')
        }
    }

    GeneratePDF(){
        let filename = 'test.pdf'
        let pdf = new jspdf('p', 'mm', 'a4');
        let pdfList = this.state.PDFs;

        html2canvas(document.getElementById('inner-container')).then(canvas => {
            pdf.addImage(canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'), 'JPEG', 0, 0, 211, 298);
            //pdf.save(filename);
        });

        pdfList.push({filename: filename, content: pdf.save(filename), contentType: 'application/pdf'})

        this.setState({
            PDFs: pdfList,
        })
    }

    SendRawEmail(){
        let to = 'myemail@email.com';
        let text = 'this is a test'
        let data = this.state.PDFs;

        $.get("/sendRaw", { to: to, subject: 'Contract Testing', text: text, data: data }, function (data) { }); 
    }
```

Here is the API:

```
app.get('/sendRaw', (request, response) => {

    var mailOptions = {
      to: request.query.to,
      bcc: request.query.bcc,
      subject: request.query.subject,
      text: request.query.text,
      attachment: request.query.data
    }

    smtpTransport.sendMail({  //email options
        from: "someemail@email.com", // sender address.  Must be the same as authenticated user if using Gmail.
        to: mailOptions.to, 
        bcc: "someemail@email.com",    // sending to itself
        subject: mailOptions.subject, // subject
        html: mailOptions.text, // body
        attachments: mailOptions.attachment,
      }, function (error, response) {  //callback
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log("Message sent");
        }

        smtpTransport.close();
      });

  })
```

I feel like I'm close to what I want to accomplish, but there must be something I'm missing here.  I'm also not sure if what I'm trying to accomplish can really even be done.  If it's possible I would like to know how I could accomplish such a feature.  If anyone has any ideas or suggestions that would help me immensely.  Thanks!

Comment: Any success?  I have a pure javascript, jsPDF and html2canvas that outputs an iFrame to  PDF, I can save the PDF and I can output to a PDF attachment but the file fails between sender and receiver, the received file can't be viewed

Comment: @Jay.Smyth yes, I was able to figure it out.  I will update this question with the solution.  I essentially needed to convert the pdf into a datauri and then pass that to nodemailer.